# How to use HTML in custom tooltip in angular charts?

Tags: angularjs, angular-chart, chart.js

Is it possible to render HTML in a tooltip on a chart using angular-chart 1.0?
I've built the chart below, but need to render two values on separate lines in the tooltip, however the br tag is appearing as text

```
<div ng-app="doughnutApp" ng-controller="DoughnutCtrl as doughnutCtrl">
  <canvas id="doughnut" 
          class="chart chart-doughnut" 
          chart-data="doughnutCtrl.labelsValues.values" 
          chart-labels="doughnutCtrl.labelsValues.labels" 
          chart-options="doughnutCtrl.chartOptions">
  </canvas>
</div>

<script>
  var app = angular.module('doughnutApp', ['chart.js']);
  app.controller('DoughnutCtrl', function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.labelsValues = {
      "labels": ["Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3", "Label 4", "Label 5", "Label 6", "Label 7", "Label 8"],
      "values": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    };

    vm.chartOptions = {
      tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
          label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            return "Line 1<br/>Line 2";
          }
        }
      }
    };
  });
</script>
```

Working plunker here: http://plnkr.co/jtOM2PIccrb87wmFZc0p

One workaround is to put one line in the "label" callback and the other in the "beforeLabel" callback, but that still wouldn't render colours, font styles, etc

Comment: reading through the  [chart.js documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-tooltip-configuration) it looks like there's no functionality to use HTML for a tooltip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use an array for "simulate" new line:

```
tooltips: {
    //mode: "label",
    callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            var legend = new Array();
            for(var i in data.datasets){
                legend.push(
                    data.datasets[i].label + ": " + parseFloat(data.datasets[i].data[tooltipItem.index])
                );
            }

            return legend;
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Thank you so much, been searching for a while for this answer. Worked for me.

Comment: Replace loop with: `return data.datasets.map(dataset => dataset.label + ': ' + parseFloat(dataset.data[tooltipItem.index]));`